# KIF 2.0 access element in UIWebview

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, testing, kif-framework, kif

Can somebody tell me how to access an input field in a uiwebview in KIF 2.0? Unfortunately I can't find anything on [KIF Framework Github](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF), neither in the documentation nor in the examples. I tried to access the input field via its id but this doesn't seem to work:

`[tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"username"];`.

Thanks in advance. And if you have some nice resources about KIF 2.0 I would be happy if you send them to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, HTML text fields get their accessibility label from `<label>` tags.  For example:

```
<label for=myField>My Field</label> <input id=myField>
```

In VoiceOver, this reads as a static text block "My Field", and a text field "My Field, Text Field, Double tap to edit."  Both in VoiceOver and regular phone use, tapping the `<label>` will cause the text field to focus.

If you call `[tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"My Field"]`, KIF will send a tap event to the label, causing `UIWebView` to focus the text field.  You can then use `[tester enterTextIntoFirstResponder:@"..."]` to enter your text.

Comment: hi brian thanks. i will try it out tomorrow morning and will check the answer if I had success.